# How can I define any number of variables without first setting the number?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, range, infinite

I want to be able to do something along the lines of this:

__*_*____ [button]

text []

text2 []

text3 []

and so on. The **__** is a space for the user to type in text. When they click the button, that text is added above where it says text [], and everything else is moved down. I thought to have a class for a line of text, and each time the user adds more text it simply makes a new iteration of that class. The problem is, I don't know how to define an infinite number of variables. Is there a way to say something along the lines of:

```
for i in range (0, number):
    g + i = Text(i)
```

So that, if number was 5, it would output g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, and g5?

I thought of doing an array, but I ran into the following problem:

I could make an array of length 6 and do:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    array[i] = Text(i)
```

but then I don't think it's possible to add a 7th one later, because I believe that once the array length is set it can't be changed.

To summarize: I need a way to make any number of variables, and then add however many more later that I want, at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a *list*, not an *array*.  Both exist in Python (lists in the core, arrays in the `array` module) and both are variable length.  To create a list with the desired strings, use

```
[Text(i) for i in range(0, 5)]
```

(which is called a *list comprehension*.  Search for this term for more information.)

Answer (score 3):

> I believe that once the array length is set it can't be changed.

Use a list and its the `append` member:

```
array.append(Text(5))
```

I'm not sure if you actually used Python arrays from the `array` package or lists, but you should be using the latter. Python lists are implemented as dynamic arrays, not linked lists. They seem the perfect fit for the problem as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use a dictionary:

```
g={}
for i in range (0, number):
  g[i] = Text(i)
```